# Convert field obtained from SQL Server to a checkbox of a datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm showing data from my contacts table to a datagridview - all good so far. This is my code as I show the information by datasource.

This is my data_layer class:

```
public DataTable Contactos_ClieProvs(String basesita, String codClie)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(conexion.CargarBase(basesita));

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("execute CONTACTOS  @tipo=13,@IdClieProv='" + codClie + "'", cnn);
        // cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        try
        {
            if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                cnn.Open();
            }
            else
            {
                cnn.Close();
                cnn.Open();
            }

            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch (SqlException ex) 
        { 
             throw ex; 
        }
        finally
        {
            cnn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex1) 
    { 
        throw ex1; 
    }

    return dt;
}
```

This is code as shown towards the datagridview:

```
private void txtcod_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ("" == "") 
        dt = negCli.DatosContacto(MODULOS.Globales.Base, txtcod.Text);
         
    bs.DataSource = dt;
    bs.AddingNew += bs_AddingNew;
    dt.RowDeleting += dt_RowDeleting;
    this.dgvcontactos.DataSource = bs;

    // this.dgvcontactos.DataSource = negCli.DatosContacto(MODULOS.Globales.Base, txtcod.Text);
    return;
}
```

Now I am looking for a way to convert this specific field "To charge" where if it is 1 the check is selected and if it is 0 it is not selected, I have tried to add it in a design way but I have not had good results, someone please can help since I am just beginning in this world.

[image]

Comment: Set `dgvcontactos.AutoGenerateColumns = false;`  and then add your columns manually (make one of those columns a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` making sure that you set the columns `DataPropertyName` to the name of your column from sql.  You may need to set `TrueValue = 1` for when it's 1 and `FalseValue = 0` for when that value is 0. You also have to make sure that the column `para_cobranza` is a boolean. Then when you call `this.dgvcontactos.DataSource = bs;` it knows how to map the columns from the datatable to the datagridview.

Comment: The field to show a checkbox has to be set to boolean.  then the zero/one coming from the databae needs to set the check box to true/false

Comment: then I have to specify the number of the column where the condition applies and convert that field to a checkbox, could you help me at the code level the logic we have.

Comment: @kenny `then I have to specify the number of the column where the condition applies` we can't see your stored procedure, it's not in your post.

Comment: the stored procedure is excute CONTACTS where a select is applied to a contacts table- the data type of for_collection is numeric (1,0)

Comment: **WARNING:** YOur code is *wide* open to injection attacks. *Never* inject your parameters, **parametrise** them,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply cast the field in your stored procedure to be BOOLEAN (or BIT if you are using MS SQL) rather than numeric(1,0) and the field will "automatically" become a CheckBox type when you create/bind it. Here would be the MS SQL example:

```
SELECT CAST(DB.Field AS BIT) FROM DB
```